# How to solve unassigned_shards in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to solve unassigned_shards in elasticsearch?
When i run command  curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'
i got following result

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 145,
  "active_shards" : 145,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 145,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your cluster only has one node, there will always be unassigned shards - those are [replica shards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/replica-shards.html). They are used to restore data when a nodes crashes. They will assign to another node automaticly as soon as your cluster has two nodes. If you dont want to have them, because u are in a local development for example, you can set the replica shard size to 0 in the index mapping. You can look up how to do that here in the [Update Indices Settings documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html).